# Why is it impossible for $f(g(x))$ to increase when $f(x)$ is increasing and $g(x)$ is decreasing?

Tags: calculus, functions

The book I am reading now states that it is impossible to find two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that the former is increasing and the latter is decreasing so that $f(g(x))$ is increasing for all $x$.

I can argue that. Let $g(x)=-e^x$ and $f(x)=x^2$. Then for all $x$, $f(g(x))$ will be increasing. Here is [the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kvp1jukn3n). Please explain if I am wrong.

Comment: @Arthur, it doesn't state about the sign of $x$. It says for **all** $x$.

Comment: f is not increasing.

Comment: Note that the function $f(x) = x^2$ is decreasing over $(-\infty,0)$ which is incidentally the range of $g(x)$.

Comment: @MartinR, sorry? Why?

Comment: Wrong example, $f(x)=x^2$ is not increasing all R.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, omg, ahaha, I am stupid. Thank you!

Comment: $-3<-2$ but $f(-3)>f(-2)$ shows that $f$ is not increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that if $x<y$ then $g(x)>g(y)$. Then $f$ is increasing so
$$f \circ g(x) > f \circ g (y)$$

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that, as many have pointed out, $f$ is not strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}$.

The statement by the book can be explained as follows.

First we have $x_1<x_2$.

Since $g$ is decreasing, we have $g(x_1)>g(x_2)$.

We know that for $a>b$, $f(a)>f(b)$ if $f$ is increasing.

Hence, $fg(x_1)>fg(x_2)$ while $x_1<x_2$.

Clearly, $fg$ cannot be increasing. In fact, it is strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that, if you have an increasing/decreasing $f(x)$, when you change x with an increasing $g(x)$, the all thing that you do is scaleing the x axis so $f(g(x))$ is stay increasing/decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume f and g are differentiable then $f'(x)>0, g'(x)<0 \implies (f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)<0.$